# Bible inerrancy and the Ashbaal→Ishboshet change

Tags: names, tanach, samuel-shmuel-book-of

In [another answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14782), someone said that Rashi thinks Ashbaal is changed to Ishboshet (sorry for spelling) as derogatory to the baal.

So Ishboshet's real name is Ashbaal but then some scribes changed that.

If that's true, then how is the bible inerrant? If people **change** the actual content of the bible with **false** information to fit their theological agenda. What am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Torah inerrancy extend to the prophets and the writings?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/does-torah-inerrancy-extend-to-the-prophets-and-the-writings)

Comment: @SethJ, I think this is actually a special case thereof. The title here should probably be more specific.

Comment: @IsaacMoses The [Ishboshet question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14772/5) was already asked. The [Na"Ch question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10525/5) was already asked. The [Torah question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7308/5) as the basis for the Na"Ch question was already asked. Between all three of those, I think the question is covered.

Comment: @SethJ, Isn't this a natural follow-on of points raised in the Ishboshet question?

Comment: @IsaacMoses IMO it would require a lot of editing to make it a valuable stand-alone question. The question of inerrancy has been addressed, the question of Ishboshet's name has been addressed. If he wants to call into question the inerrancy of TaNa"Ch based on his interpretation of the Ishboshet question (and answers), I think he has to first establish that his interpretation is correct. Even then he is arguing, not asking, so I would still close it as not constructive or not a real question, or possibly even off-topic, as I'm sure there are other forums that address it (Hermeneutics.SE?).

Comment: @SethJ, what do you think now?

Comment: @msh210 I think it's a lot better now. You have an answer? The question is now on Rashi rather than on all Judaism, though. Do you think that's the intent, or do you think it's the way it needs to be for the question to stand?

Comment: @SethJ, I guess that's the intent.

Comment: I am aware that other explanation is also possible. I am learning. It's just that this is the most popular explanation namely that the writer/editor of the bible deliberately wrote a wrong name, which doesn't sound very honest to me. But again, it's possible that ishbaal himself call himself ishbal in which case there is no problem. But still, we don't know that for sure do we?

Comment: @msh210 that's NOT the intent. My intent is not showing you're wrong. My intent is to get explanation.

Comment: In christianity copies of gospel said that pilate offer to free jesus barabas. Latter copy simply erase jesus out of jesus barabas to avoid "confusion". We call that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pious_fraud .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This example does not seem to be one of Biblical errancy. [Rashi](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14254&st=&pgnum=69) was saying that the **author** of this particular work within the Bible chose a derogatory nickname, replacing Baal for the negative Boshet. (Or perhaps even contemporaries of Ish Boshet called him that.) Rashi was not saying that **scribes** edited out Ish Boshet and replaced the original Biblical text.

Comment: see the Malbim quoted here as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ish-bosheth#The_other_name:_Ashba.27al

Comment: Okay so we don't know for sure? Also does that mean the author of bible deliberately wrote false name? That sounds a lot like lying to me.

Comment: What do you mean "we don't know for sure"? Did you read Rashi inside in Hebrew to get the sense of his words? This is one commentator's explanation. There was no **one** author of the Bible. The book of Shmuel was traditionally authored by Shmuel the prophet. Is it lying if I refer to George Bush as Dubya? If I call General Patreus "G. Betray Us"? Is it lying if, out of misplaced religious scruples, write Ado-shem instead of Adonai? If I refer disparagingly to males I look down upon as "those who pisseth against the wall", if in fact they use outhouses? Scholars of literature understand this.

Comment: Now that makes sense. Thanks for explanation. Still another question should be ask, why Saul named his son Ishbal? Does saul worship baal?

Comment: Fascinating question. I would answer: (a) perhaps, though one would expect the Biblical text to mention it; (b) Saul had concubines (see e.g. 2 Sam 3:7), so maybe they worshiped Baal; (c) perhaps Baal just means 'lord' or 'master' (see Hosea), in which case it is a reference to Hashem, yet triggered editing / nicknaming by a Biblical author. One would need to make this work in harmony with the present Q/A, though. See here: http://books.google.com/books?id=TjcpAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA32&ots=5-NH_wOXdk&dq=ishbaal%20saul%20idolatry&pg=PA32#v=onepage&q=ishbaal%20saul%20idolatry&f=false